# running iptables with rhel7.2 image with in docker

Tags: git, bash, docker, iptables

while running iptables inside docker with rhel7.2 image it is working fine.
But when I am trying to run docker with some rules to it then it is not at all starting.

**Here is my docker file**

```
#######Simplest Docker file which I used for building image and it works from marathon if you dont give cmd or args ########
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7.2
ADD rhel7.2.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7.2.repo
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum install iptables -y
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
######### Dockerfile END ####

###to run the docker
sudo docker run -it /bin/bash -c "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.254.1:10004"
```

**Please let me know what's wrong ?**

Answer (score 0):

If it runs without providing args, I suspect the issue is that you're overriding the image's `CMD`; By calling `/bin/bash -c ...` you're overriding the `/usr/sbin/init`, so iptables won't be started.

You can *start* the container (without arguments), then open an interactive session in the container using `docker exec -it <containername> bash` to make modifications to the iptables setup.